# Mongos + AutoScaling

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

We're currently running a cluster of application servers that are under an autoscaling group in AWS. Each of this application servers has it's own instance of mongos running, so the application just connects to localhost to gain access to the MongoDB cluster.

I read in the documentation that the balancer is a process running under mongos. What happens if the server is scaled down and the balancer is running in that server? Would it be possible to say that only this mongos instance at this server ip will run the balancer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the documentation explicitly states that every mongos has a balancer process which is associated with it which is responsible for distributing data (evenly) in a sharded collection across different shard. By default 'balancer' process is enabled. Optionally it can be disabled.

Hence,

> 1. If a server is scaled down 'balancer' will still be running on server with mongos
> 2. Only servers that run mongos instance will have 'balancer' running.

Comment: So what happens if the server with mongos gets shutdown during scale down operation? Will the balancer stop?

Comment: Obviously yes,  if mongos running on a server shuts down then the balancer will stop as well.